# AspectJ with Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am working on a spring boot microservice. I am new to AspectJ. I am trying to create an aspect for logging. This is my aspect component.

```
@Aspect 
@Component
public class UserAcessAspect {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserAcessAspect.class);

@Before("execution(com.profectus.insights.service.impl.InsightsElasticityServiceImpl.*(..))")
public void beforeAdvice(Joinpoint joinPoint, InsightRequest request) {
    logger.info("ASPECTJ------------------->>>>>>>>>>>>");
}
```

}

I am getting the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed:     
expecting 'name pattern' at character position 78
execution(com.profectus.insights.service.impl.InsightsElasticityServiceImpl.*(..))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should read

- the [AspectJ documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/docs.php)
- the [Spring AOP manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop)

in order to learn the syntax first.

What is wrong with your pointcut is that the method signature has no return type. You want to write something like

```java
execution(* com.profectus.insights.service.impl.InsightsElasticityServiceImpl.*(..))
```